# How to run JavaFX jar with JRE7 on MAC OS Lion 10.7.5?

Tags: macos, jar, path, javafx-2, java

I have created a bundled JavaFX application jar with ANT on Windows 8 O.S. , 64 bit machine. I have JavaFx2.0 and Java 1.7.0_09 installed on my Window O.S.

```
<target name="CreatingJars" depends="Compiling" description="generate the distribution" >
                <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
                        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" classpath="${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>

                        <mkdir dir="${WorkingFolder}/temp/libs"/>
                    <copy todir="${WorkingFolder}/temp/libs">
                    <fileset file="${WorkingFolder}/CustomJars/ProjectLib.jar">
                    </fileset>
                    </copy>
                    <copy todir="${WorkingFolder}/temp/libs">
                    <fileset dir="${WorkingFolder}/libs">
                    </fileset>
                </copy>

                <fx:jar destfile="${WorkingFolder}/${app.name}.jar">
                <fx:application mainClass="${main.class}"/>
                <fx:resources>
                    <fx:fileset dir="${WorkingFolder}/temp/"/>
                </fx:resources>

                <fileset dir="${WorkingFolder}/build"/>
                <fileset dir="${WorkingFolder}/resources"/>
                </fx:jar>
    </target>
```

When I am trying to run that JavaFX application jar on MAC OS Lion 10.7.5 using

java -jar application.jar

It always shows a dialog "The application require a newer version of Java Run-time" with download link. Even I have downloaded and successfully installed it on my MAC machine but it still shows me the same window.

java -version is always point to 1.6.

Then I searched for Java Preferences to point the current JRE 1.7 but I could find Java Preferences at Applications -> Utilities -> Java -> Java Preferences.

I would like to know -- how to run JavaFX jar with JRE7 on MAC OS Lion 10.7.5? Is their any other way to run the JavaFX application JAR with JRE7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [related forum post](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2479860&tstart=0).

To run the app for the latest installed Oracle jre version:

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar application.jar
```

To run the app for a given installed jdk version:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
java -jar application.jar
```

Comment: Thanks but I have downloaded the JRE 1.7 and I would like to run JAR with JRE 1.7. Do I need to download the whole JAVA 1.7 on MAC to run the JAR?

Comment: Updated answer to include JRE based execution in addition to selected JDK based execution.

Comment: +1. Thanks. But still unable to run the jar. Please refer related post.