# How can I run JRE 7 on Mac 10.6

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, java

This may be a longshot, but I NEED to get Java JRE 7 running on Mac 10.6.  The official documentation states

> Mac OS X System Requirements
>
> - Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion) or later.
> - Administrator privileges for installation 64-bit browser

Is there any way I can trick the java JRE 7 into installing itself on OSX 10.6?  Is there some community version of a JRE 7?

Comment: I highly recommend not doing that because you end up getting some strange and unpredictable behavior for you applications and you end up spending a lot of time trying understand and debug. why don't you just upgrade ?

Comment: user717630 I would if they were my own machines, but my client said there is a 0% chance of them upgrading.

Comment: To be clear - this is ***NOT*** a dupe of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102761, which this post has been flagged as. They refer to different OSX versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, just follow what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536667/how-to-install-java-jdk-7-on-snow-leopard/13999527#13999527) suggests. I successfully installed JDK 7 update 11 a couple of weeks ago. However I have only used it for some development, and am not sure if it runs e.g. Swing apps without issues.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Easiest is most likely to install virtual box and run Ubuntu inside.

---

EDIT: The comments indicate that this is not for hobby use but a client. I would personally never base a commercial solution on unsupported software, and I hope it has been made  absolutely clear to the client what this can result in.

A better solution might be recompiling your Java program for Java 6 (use the Eclipse compiler with -source and -target) and run it under Java 6.  If you cannot do this - as you said *NEED* - then open a new question asking how to backport that facility to Java 6.

Comment: Sorry, but "No." is just clearly not true. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @zagyi being able to _install_ a program under an unsupported operating system does not mean that it _runs_ correctly which I - and most likely also the OP - would consider a requirement for being able to say yes instead of no.   Especially for such a complex system as a modern JVM.

Comment: You are probably right, however I answered to the question. "Is there any way I can trick the java JRE 7 into installing itself on OSX 10.6?". I guess the OP also realizes what it means to install a JRE in an unsupported platform, but if he doesn't have any other option, he can at least give it a try.

Comment: If you answer, write a proper answer instead of a comment saying I am wrong.  This allows the OP to select it as the most helpful answer and does not pollute other answers with non-constructive comments.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I just thought my post doesn't deserve an answer being barely more than a reference to another thread. I'll add an answer now which you can downvote :), and will remove my comments from here if I can.

Comment: Technically you are right Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen.  On the other hand zagyi did present a reasonable solution, which actually solved the problem (JRE 7 installed via Pacifist).  upvotes for both of you, but zagyi delivered.

Comment: @zagyi I am not interested in down voting your answer, and haven't. That does not mean I agree with you, though, but it is two different directions.

Comment: @Daisetsu your recent comments indicate that this is not for hobby use but a client.  I would personally never base a commercial solution on unsupported software, and I hope you have made it absolutely clear to your client what this can result in. Also software exists to retrofit a java program to an earlier version of java.